# Target Encoding: missing value imputation before or after encoding

Tags: random-forest, missing-data, data-imputation, categorical-encoding, feature-engineering

I want to perform a target encoding for my categorical features although I am not sure when to perform the data imputation if any of them has missing values. Let's say I have a few continuous features, Cnt1-Cnt5 (without NA's) and two categorical features, Cat1 and Cat2, with Cat2 having missing values. Let's also assume that I want to use Random Forest as an imputation method. Which approach would be the correct one?

1. Impute Cat2 treating Cat1 and Cnt1-Cnt5 as predictors in RF and then perform target encoding on categorical variables.
2. Target encode Cat2 for non missing and Cat1, build RF and impute missings for Cat2 (which is now numeric, not categorical).
3. Any other approach?

We can generalize this question and ask whether we should impute missings for any kind of variable (including continuous) before or after target encoding?

I see at least one benefit of imputation after target encoding - if there are unseen levels of categorical variable present in the test data (which will result in NA's in the test set after performing target encoding), those would be easily imputed by RF built on training data, without any potential error due to new levels.

Comment: How many levels do the categorical variables have?

Comment: Let's consider two scenarios: a) Cat2 has 50 levels, b) Cat2 has 10 levels. Cat1 is 5 level variable.

Comment: Can you please add that information as an edit to the Question?